# What skill should a Tech-priest use for reprogramming machines?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-1e

What skill should one use for tasks that require reprogramming machines or (apparently)  designing entirely new software?

Tech-use and Security seem to operate on a mechanical/physical aspect, as all the eventual Trade skill-groups (like Technomat) do. Should I make a new skill like Trade (Programmer)? Or even Trade (Software Designer)? Trade (Software Engineering)? :P

From what I read in the books, Logic could be the right skill for this job, but it's not said explicitly.
EDIT: it's said in the Logic skill that Logic is theory and Tech-Use is practice.

Answer (score 11):

There doesn't seem to be a definitive book answer for this one.  I'm actually inclined to think that this is on purpose, and there's no such skill - all such rolls should be made on `Tech-use` or an appropriate trade skill.

I don't think you should add `Trade (Programmer)` or `Trade (Software Engineer)`, because I don't believe those professions actually exist in 40k.

This is to do with universe feel.  40k Imperial and Chaos tech is mystical and badly understood; while there must obviously be software and programs, they don't see much *abstract* computing.  40k doesn't seem to have any common equivalent to the general-purpose computing device; almost all software is *embedded control software*, tied to a specific machine.  I can't think of any reference in the source material to a programmer who isn't also an *engineer*.

Indeed, given the focus of the 40k tech-base on reproducing standard pattern devices and then jury-rigging modifications, there may actually not be such a thing as a general-purpose high-level programming language in most of 40k space - that requires a degree of technical understanding that probably only the Tau and Eldar have.  Quite possibly each category of devices just has its own embedded programming language, and learning to code in it goes with learning to build and maintain the device.

So I'm inclined to think that rolls to handle programming should be on the appropriate skill for whatever device the PC is trying to modify or reprogram.

Comment: Shouldn't SCT extend to "programming blocks" too? I agree that the software in W40K would be in the majority embedded software, but there must be some sort of formalization. For example there could be a standard database manager, a standard network protocol, a standard office suite, and so on.
While I understand there is no formal training in software engineering, it may happen that an algorithm is necessary, or that you need to add a functionality to a program, and while it could be seen as rituals and stuff, you still need a skill to do it, and I can't find a suitable one.
Out of spaaaaace.

Comment: @lunadir: There's no evidence that 40k has a standard network protocol, just a mass of individual protocols used by specific gadgets.  Much less an office suite as we understand it.  It's generally going to be `Tech-use`, but the key is: forget that it's software, use whatever skill is appropriate to do it in hardware.  "Write addon to office" should be viewed as "use the computer that you're running office on" for skill purposes.  There is no generic algorithmic coding, because they've lost the concept of generalised algorithm.

Comment: I know there's no evidence, but it was a question: shouldn't SCT cover software too? Only hardware? | I am not sure that programming could entirely be lost, whatever they are using - if they need to be something more than just a 'user' - then they need algorithms too. Maybe simple scripts, maybe just flowcharts, but it's impossible they have everything already precooked, that it's just putting physical objects together: they need customization. I would "forget that it's software", but sometimes things are just software, sometimes they're only hardware, it can't be left aside.

Comment: @lunadir: Sure, there's software involved, but the *skill to roll in game* should be based on the hardware.  40k people learn programming as part of the handling of specific devices, not as a general abstraction.  It's not that they have everything precooked; it's that they don't have .Net or Java, just cruder embedded languages.

(This is getting kinda involved; can you explain what needs improving in the answer directly, or should we take this to chat?)

Comment: this could well continue in a chat, but I won't be available today (other than that, I'm not confident with the names in english, and I need time to think, but it could probably be arranged in a chat). Still, I have one or two things to say: even if it was embedded languages, I doubt it would be low level, because it would imply knowing the device pretty well, and in W40K mostly they don't. That's way I think it would be more of a visual thing. In regard to examples, it's been a years-long campaign, and I'm not the tech-priest there, and this programming thing was rare. I need to think

Comment: I'm with @Tynam.  Knowing generalized algorithms or any other kind of skill that, outside of game, we would call "computer science" as opposed to "programming," is unknown and therefore heretical.  (And therefore good cause for an Inquisitor to give you one in the head from his bolter.  That will keep the software engineers I play with from metagaming next time we play Dark Heresy!)

Comment: In the WH40K universe, you don't program things - you perform specific rituals to bind machine spirits into the device, or to implore the existing machine spirits to act in different ways. Blood sacrifice might be involved in extreme cases; In that respect, it's no different to today's programming practices.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. As I said, the Logic skill covers problem solving, so algorithms don't even need to be Forbidden Lore :P | So I'd put it like this:
-How do I reprogram machines?
-You don't (with the exception of an extremely able and heretic tech-priest).

Comment: @lunadir: I think you _can_ reprogram machines to do other tasks (or "Suborn the Machine Spirit to abandon it's duties"), but it should be treated the same way as repair of that machine would be.  What you *can't* do in 40k is write a general-purpose virus or program - it's strictly one device at a time.  (Again, Tau probably could.)

Comment: Reprogramming a machine is doable without being heretical, it just depends on how you go about it. For example, the Litany of Data Integrity is used to change the instructions that the holy machine spirit in your cogitator uses to perform your daily backups. In functional terms you are changing a script and reprogramming a part of the system, in world terms you aren't programming but instead going through the sacred motions to change the instructions that are given to the machine spirit. A heretical action would be to rewrite the twenty thousand year old code in the backup daemon.

Comment: Tynam: sure, the Tau are fully aware of the technology they are using, they hadn't had problems like the humans.

@Colin: yeah, they're probably executing scripts, changing parameters and permits, moving and deleting files, but they're not altering the purpose of the machine, and usually they don't know exactly what they are doing -- from what I understand the only knowledge of that would be heretical, and that is a point in my question.

Answer (score 5):

The adventures seem to use Tech-Use for programming and hacking tasks. Therefore, Tech-Use seems to be the relevant skill.

Comment: It's not much a matter of (this) adventure, it's a matter of fiddling with technology, which happens pretty often in this game (expecially when you're a tech-priest...). | Not only `Tech-Use` seems to be exclusively hardware-related, but using one skill for everything seems a bit like cheating (and a bit boring).

Comment: Still, the in-print adventures use Tech-Use for programming and database operations. It's the skill the dev team chooses for the answers.

Comment: Maybe I will search novels about tech-priests (if only I could decide).